# Why does image_tab behaves inconsistently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view in which I try to render some images. 
The images' paths are all derived dynamically from the database. 
The problem is that image_tab as I am tracing some times renders 
    'assets/imagepath'
while some other times renders
    'images/imagepath'

```
<div class="col-sm-9 guess-button">
  <div class="row" id="cards">
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1 .col-xs-offset-1">
      <% if @attempts && @attempts > 0 %>

          <%= image_tag @deal.at(0), class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif", class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% end %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
        <% if @attempts && @attempts > 1 %>
          <%= image_tag @deal.at(1), class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif", class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% end %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
       <% if @attempts && @attempts > 2 %>
        <%= image_tag @deal.at(2), class: "img-responsive" %>
      <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif", class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% end %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
       <% if @attempts && @attempts > 3 %>
          <%= image_tag @deal.at(3), class: "img-responsive" %>
      <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif", class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% end %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
       <% if @attempts && @attempts > 4 %>
         <%= image_tag @deal.at(4), class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif", class: "img-responsive"%>
      <% end %>
     </div>
  </div> <!-- ROW -->   
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the code with us please?

Comment: you should consider using a partial for your blocks or at least loop through them, not just hardcode them